# iOS Swift: Retrieving parse backend data in orderByAscending not working

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2

Setup: XCODE 7.1 Beta, Swift iOS 9

I am trying to retrive my data in order (orderByAscending) from the key value of type Number from Parse.com database.

OrderBy works when I am NOT retrieving images and the retrieved objects are directly inside the findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock.

```
var prodCst = NSMutableArray()
var prodNam = NSMutableArray()

func loadData() {
 let query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Main")
    query.orderByAscending("ProductCost")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{(objects:[AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if(error == nil){
            for object in objects as! [PFObject!] {
               let pName = object["ProductName"] as! String
               let pCost = object["ProductCost"]! as! Int

               self.prodNam.addObject(pName)
               self.prodCst.addObject(pCost)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But as I am retrieving images I have to use getDataInBackgroundWithBlock inside findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock. Which rearranges the retrieved objects in random order.

Can someone tell me how to resolve this? I want to get the data in ascending/decending order of the Cost together with the respective images.

In Parse,

Key "ProductCost" is of type "Number" and has Int values.

Code is as below:

```
var prodCst = NSMutableArray()
var prodNam = NSMutableArray()
var prodImage : Array<UIImage> = []

func loadData() {
let query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Main")
    query.orderByAscending("ProductCost")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{(objects:[AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if(error == nil){
            for object in objects as! [PFObject!] {
               let pName = object["ProductName"] as! String
               let pImage = object["ProductImage"] as! PFFile
               let pCost = object["ProductCost"]! as! Int
          pImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
              if (error == nil) {

                let retrivedFoodImage: UIImage = UIImage(data:imageData!)!
                self.prodImage.append(retrivedFoodImage)
                self.prodNam.addObject(pName)
                self.prodCst.addObject(pCost)
            }
         })
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: The ordering should still be preserved but the images are being loaded asynchronously. That means that there is no guarantee when or in what order the *images* will be loaded, however the original query results should be ordered just fine. Add some print statements to make sure this is the case. Otherwise, it could be a bug

Comment: @Russell I tried checking with print command. What I see on screen is what I am getting in the print statement. All random. Do you think that there is any other way to retrieve the objects? May be pining in background (parse local storage)? But I am guessing that if the data is retrieved in random order inside the getDataInBackgroundWithBlock block, it will be same in the local storage.

Comment: Right, there is no guarantees on the ordering inside of `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock`. If you are printing inside there, the ordering will be wrong. Try using the print statement at the beginning of the for loop to confirm that the ordering is correct.

Comment: I believe the answer to your question will be that you want to restructure your view. You can show the name and cost immediately and then use a `PFImageView` to asynchronously load the images. `PFImageView` is included in the `ParseUI` framework and automatically takes care of loading and updating the images for you